# Using comprehensions in arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, generator-expression

Consider this:

```
>>> set((x,y) for x in range(1,3) for y in range(1,3))                                                                                                                                                            
{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)}
```

However, if I just take the argument I used above:

```
>>> (x,y) for x in range(1,3) for y in range(1,3)
```

I get `SyntaxError`

What exactly does `set` get in my first call? An object? An expression? Are they different things?

Technically speaking, `set` expects **at most** 1 argument, so I don't understand how the first expression works but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) has outer parentheses, but it is permitted to omit them when it is the sole argument of a function. Omitting the outer parentheses in this situation is no more than syntactic sugar.

So the expression:

```
set((x,y) for x in range(1,3) for y in range(1,3))
```

is exactly the same as:

```
set(((x,y) for x in range(1,3) for y in range(1,3)))
```